# Problem using UnitConvert

Tags: units, conversion

As we know in physics, power = torque * (angular velocity). But when I use `UnitConvert` to convert a quantity expressing power/(angular velocity) into newton-meters, `UnitConvert` fails.

[image: result]

How can they be incompatible units? How do I deal with it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"Revolutions"` is not immediately recognized as a special unit. So, preprocess first with `UnitSimplify[]`:

```
UnitConvert[UnitSimplify[Quantity[335, "Kilowatts"]/
                         Quantity[3000, "Revolutions"/"Minutes"], 
                         UnityDimensions -> {"AngleUnit"}], "Newtons" "Meters"]
   Quantity[3350/π, "Meters"*"Newtons"]
```

Answer (score 2):

In MMA 13.3, the selected answer no longer works. The following uses the newer `RevolutionUnit` unit dimension. Not sure when it changed.

```
UnitConvert[Quantity[335, "Kilowatts"] /
  UnitSimplify[Quantity[1, "FullAngle"] Quantity[3000, "Revolutions"/"Minutes"], 
  UnityDimensions -> {"RevolutionUnit", "AngleUnit"}], 
  "Newtons" "Meters"
]

(* Out[] *)
Quantity[3350/Pi, "Meters"*"Newtons"]
```